# I need to use TableLayout...I have the .jar downloaded...don't know how to use it

Tags: java, layout

Making my first game and it is along the lines of Advance Wars/Fire Emblem. For that reason the mystical layout manager, TableLayout seems like a no-brainer.

I installed the jar and now I feel like I'm the no-brainer. After a long while fighting with it in Eclipse (resulting in the structure I put below), I've come to SO.

How do I get my class files to use my jar? The thing you are seeing is a copy-pasted demo and not following any kind of good Java convention. I know these are no-nos. As soon as I fool with TableLayout some in gridbag.java (the example I stole) I'm going to delete it and implement it in my actual class files/

[image: What is going on here.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist option: right click on project name -> build path -> configure build path, then clik on libraries tab and click "Add external jars". In file dialog find your jar.

Second option(better): create folder colled "libs" in your project, copy your jar into that folder and do the same as the first option but chose "Add jars" instead of "Add external jars". You should be able to add jar from libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the jar and Add to Build Path.
Then you should be able to use autocomplete (control + space) on the class name to add your import.
Or try control + 1 to quick fix the error on the class name